# Blitz code produces different output

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to use weave.blitz to improve the performance of the following numpy code:

```
def fastIteration(self):
    g = self.grid
    nx,ny = g.ux.shape

    uxold = g.old_ux
    ux = g.ux
    ux[0:,1:-1] = uxold[0:,1:-1] + ReI* (uxold[0:,2:] - 2*uxold[0:,1:-1] + uxold[0:,0:-2])

    g.setBC()
    g.old_ux = ux.copy()
```

In this code g is the computational grid. Which consist of two different fields ux and uxold. The old is simply used for temporary storage of the variables. In the complete Code around 95% of the runtime is spend in the fastIteration method, therefore even a simple performance gain would reduce the amount of hours spend executing this code significantly.

The output of the numpy method looks as if:

[image: numpy result]

As this code is my bottleneck I want to improve the speed by using weave blitz. This method looks like:

```
def blitzIteration(self):
    ### does not work correct so far
    g = self.grid
    nx,ny = g.ux.shape

    uxold = g.old_ux
    ux = g.ux
    expr = "ux[0:,1:-1] = uxold[0:,1:-1] + ReI* (uxold[0:,2:] - 2*uxold[0:,1:-1] + uxold[0:,0:-2])"
    weave.blitz(expr, check_size=0)
    g.setBC()
    g.old_ux = ux.copy()
```

However this does not produce the correct output:
[image: output for blitz code]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in `weave.blitz` (reproduced, filed and [fixed](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/2422). There's more information about the actual bug there).

I thought it was odd to write `0:` instead of the shorter `:` to get a full slice so I replaced all those slices and voilà, it worked.

I don't really know where the bug lies, but the [`expr_code`](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/weave/blitz_tools.py#L53) generated by `weave.blitz` is slightly different:

- When using `0:`

  ```
  ipdb> expr_code
  'ux_blitz_buggy(blitz::Range(0,_end),blitz::Range(1,Nux_blitz_buggy(1)-1-1))=uxold(blitz::Range(0,_end),blitz::Range(1,Nuxold(1)-1-1))+ReI*(uxold(blitz::Range(0,_end),blitz::Range(2,_end))-2*uxold(blitz::Range(0,_end),blitz::Range(1,Nuxold(1)-1-1))+uxold(blitz::Range(0,_end),blitz::Range(0,Nuxold(1)-2-1)));\n'
  ```
- When using `:`

  ```
  ipdb> expr_code
  'ux_blitz_not_buggy(_all,blitz::Range(1,Nux_blitz_not_buggy(1)-1-1))=uxold(_all,blitz::Range(1,Nuxold(1)-1-1))+ReI*(uxold(_all,blitz::Range(2,_end))-2*uxold(_all,blitz::Range(1,Nuxold(1)-1-1))+uxold(_all,blitz::Range(0,Nuxold(1)-2-1)));\n'
  ```

So, `blitz::Range(0,_end)` becomes `_all` and they behave in a different way.

For convenience, here is a complete script that reproduces the problem and will only succeed while the problem exists.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.weave import blitz


def test_blitz_bug(N=4):
    ReI = 1.2
    ux_blitz_buggy, ux_blitz_not_buggy, ux_np = np.zeros((N, N)), np.zeros((N, N)), np.zeros((N, N))
    uxold = np.random.randn(N, N)
    ux_np[0:,1:-1] = uxold[0:,1:-1] + ReI* (uxold[0:,2:] - 2*uxold[0:,1:-1] + uxold[0:,0:-2])
    expr_buggy = 'ux_blitz_buggy[0:,1:-1] = uxold[0:,1:-1] + ReI* (uxold[0:,2:] - 2*uxold[0:,1:-1] + uxold[0:,0:-2])'
    expr_not_buggy = 'ux_blitz_not_buggy[:,1:-1] = uxold[:,1:-1] + ReI* (uxold[:,2:] - 2*uxold[:,1:-1] + uxold[:,0:-2])'
    blitz(expr_buggy)
    blitz(expr_not_buggy)
    assert not np.allclose(ux_blitz_buggy, ux_np)
    assert np.allclose(ux_blitz_not_buggy, ux_np)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_blitz_bug()
```

Comment: @jordeca: here it is: 
`$ python blitz_bug.py`
`$ python -c"import scipy; print scipy.__version__"`
0.13.0.dev-639ef30
`$ python -c"import numpy; print numpy.__version__"`
1.7.1
`$ uname -a`
Linux ratatoskr 2.6.32-45-generic #104-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 19 21:20:09 UTC 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux